# My PC loses the bluetooth firmware every time I restart it

Tags: bluetooth, asus, firmware

I have to re-update the bluetooth firmware every time I restart.

~$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-28-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=54775b42-3ac8-4219-b6d5-defcb23797b7 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

Disregard, I restarted it again this time after installing the firmware for the 5th or sixth time, now it seems to work fine.

Comment: Edit to include `cat /proc/cmdline` as I am not sure how that is possible

Comment: If it happens again, skip downloading the firmware file and see if just `sudo modprobe -r btusb` then `sudo modprobe btusb` fixes it.  The Atheros bluetooth modules suffered a problem when its driver attempted to load the firmware too early in the boot process